# storing non keyvalue pair data in HBase tables

Tags: hbase

Using HBase we can save Big Data.However this data has to be key value pairs.what about storing any data which was in sql table which was not key value pair.How do save that in hbase table?
thanks

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to store? Multiple columns (like RDBMS)? Or just single values?

Comment: multiple columns same a RDBMS table data.

Answer (score 1):

Hbase in HAdoop Is "NOSQL Format". Hive Supports for SQL Format. You can try  loading data in Hive. In Hbase data will be in Column Oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the primary key of the RDBMS table as the row key.  Other columns can correspond to different columns of the HBase table (some or different column families)